# Remove stray text URL from tour answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, tour

The Tour page is now showing a stray imgur.com URL above the accepted answer:

> [image: stray imgur.com URL]

I've confirmed that this is happening on both Firefox and Chrome.  The URL happens to be that of the user's icon.  And it's not limited to one site; at least [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour), [Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/tour), and [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour) are affected.

Comment: I would guess it's on all sites- It's on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the errant piece of code and removed it.

With you in the next build.